# JSON serialize a class and change property casing with Python

Tags: python, json, serialization, camelcasing

I'd like to create a JSON representation of a class and change the property names automatically from `snake_case` to `lowerCamelCase`, as I'd like to comply with PEP8 in Python and also the JavaScript naming conventions (and maybe even more importantly, the backend I'm communicating to uses `lowerCamelCase`).

I prefer to use the standard `json` module, but I have nothing against using another, open source library (e.g. [`jsonpickle`](http://jsonpickle.github.io/) might solve my issue?).

```
>>> class HardwareProfile:
...     def __init__(self, vm_size):
...             self.vm_size = vm_size
>>> hp = HardwareProfile('Large')
>>> hp.vm_size
'Large'
### ### What I want ### ###
>>> magicjson.dumps(hp)
'{"vmSize": "Large"}'
### ### What I have so far... ### ###
>>> json.dumps(hp, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)
'{"vm_size": "Large"}'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to create a function to transform the snake_case keys to camelCase. You can easily do that using `.split`, `.lower`, and `.title`.

```
import json

class HardwareProfile:
    def __init__(self, vm_size):
        self.vm_size = vm_size
        self.some_other_thing = 42
        self.a = 'a'

def snake_to_camel(s):
    a = s.split('_')
    a[0] = a[0].lower()
    if len(a) > 1:
        a[1:] = [u.title() for u in a[1:]]
    return ''.join(a)

def serialise(obj):
    return {snake_to_camel(k): v for k, v in obj.__dict__.items()}

hp = HardwareProfile('Large')
print(json.dumps(serialise(hp), indent=4, default=serialise))
```

**output**

```
{
    "vmSize": "Large",
    "someOtherThing": 42,
    "a": "a"
}
```

You *could* put `serialise` in a `lambda`, but I think it's more readable to write it as a proper `def` function.